# Android Studio "Sources for Android API Platform 30 Not Found"

Tags: java, android

[Error when i try download the package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnftf.png)

Not matter what I do I can't seem to download the package. I receive an error.

Comment: What version of the Android studio you are using?

Comment: Its version 4.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Sources for API 30 have just been released.

[image: SDK Manager with Sources for Android 30 installed]

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/android11-release

#### Original answer

Sources for API 30 are not out yet. You will be able to download these sources when they're released.

The sources are out after the stable version of the OS is released.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your sdk tools is somehow gets corrupted, So Try reinstalling android studio is to be a good option.